# How can I save a Mat image to QByteArray?

Tags: qt, opencv, qbytearray

I need to transfer a processed image file to my through TCP. Now I have no idea about how to convert a Mat to a Qbytearray,i want the Qbytearray is a encode image file, so I can save it easily in my web application.
I tried to use imencode to save Mat to a vector, then convert it to Qbytearray,but i fall. The Program just crashed. Thanks.

```
vector<uchar> tempdata;
imencode(".tif",img1,tempdata);
QByteArray data(reinterpret_cast<char*>(tempdata.data(),tempdata.size()));
```

The error is: The inferior stopped becaused it received a signal from the operating system. The error happened in the final line.

Comment: A query: will the application that will read the data after transferring it be made with Qt?

Comment: A simple way to convert the Mat to QImage, and this is easily converted to QByteArray.

Comment: my image is a little large.So it save as tif. QImage seems cannot deal with ".tif" image.

Comment: something like `QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(tempdata.data()), tempdata.size());` should work

Comment: I have solved the question,Like Miki said,I just wrote the error code.